# Requiring javascript from files overriding assets of a rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I wrote a rails engine and want to be able to customize it in any application mounting it.

[ENGINE/]app/assets/my_engine/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require ./engine_specific
//= require ./engine_customization
```

[APP/]app/assets/my_engine/engine_customization.js:

```
//= require selectize

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').selectize();
});
```

This causes a js error (selectize is not a function)

I tried requiring other files/libs and none get loaded by sprockets.

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is actually a bug in sprockets.

EDIT:

[ENGINE/]app/views/layouts/my_engine/application.html.haml:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title My Engine
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "my_engine/application", media: "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "my_engine/application"
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    = render 'my_engine/shared/header'
    #content
      #wrapper
        = yield
```

Comment: why do you require js ...directly include it in js file and then try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that mixing engine and application layouts is fairly tricky so I took a different approach. One that also gems like devise seem to use:

I wrote generators in my gem that copy the views to the app and others that create decorators for controllers in which one must specify the application layout. It has some caveats though: If your layout contains views using path helpers (i.e. navbars) you need to prefix the helpers with "main_app.". So blog_post_path becomes main_app.blog_post_path and polymorphic_path([:edit, :admin, @resource]) becomes main_app.polymorphic_path... and so on.

Another thing is instance variables or before_filters that your application controller might define and are needed by views rendered by the layout. These you need to define in the controller decorator(s) too.

Answer (score 0):

By default only the app's application.js manifest is precompiled by sprockets.
So you have 2 options:

A)

require the `my_engine/application.js` within
the app's js manifest

```
//app/assets/javascripts/application.js

//= require myengine/application.js
```

B)
add the `my_engine/application.js` to assets.precompile array and then include it with a `javascript_include_tag`

```
 #engine.rb

 initializer "myengine.precompile" do |app|
   app.config.assets.precompile += %w(application.js)
 end

 #views/foos/show.html.erb

 javascript_include_tag 'myengine/application.js'
```

Comment: I gave A) a try but still get the same error. This is because /app/assets/javascripts/application.js is never included. The engine has its own layout which only includes /app/assets/javascripts/my_engine/application.js

Comment: plz post the code of the layout, where you are includuing application.js. If you want to include another asset file then the default application manifeest you have to add it to `assets.precompile`

Comment: I just noticed that I had already implemented B) of your answer. application.js and application.css are both in the precompile array. I edited my question to include the layout.